# Count number of occurrences in Google Sheets, with multiple criteria and not considering duplicates in the row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm looking to count the number of rows that contain a certain text (specified in the adjacent cell), from a specific range, on the basis that the criteria have been met.

I currently have this formula nearly completed, but it is counting duplicate occurrences in the same row more than once - I would like to ignore any duplicates and only count them once per row.

The current formula that I have got is as follows:
=countif(flatten(filter('Data Input'!$K$2:$Z$15000,'Data Input'!$J$2:$J$15000=$B$2)),K883)

Some notes:

- K883 is the cell of reference, which I'm trying to match in the K:Z columns.
- $B$2 is the cell that needs to exist in column J of the Data Input tab, for it to be eligible for counting.
- If K883 is the word "The" and in columns K:Z of the Data Input tab says "The" twice in the same row (assuming the $b$2 condition is met), I want this to only be counted once. However, the current formula has it shown twice.

Hope I'm not too far off. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flattening the data row by row with a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465), like this:

`=arrayformula( count( search( " " & K883 & " ", transpose( query( transpose( filter(" " & 'Data Input'!$K$2:$Z & " ", 'Data Input'!$J$2:$J = $B$2) ), "", 9^9 ) ) ) ) )`

The enclosing spaces are for avoiding matching words that contain `the`, such as `thesaurus` and `Athens`.

To match case, use `find()` instead of `search()`.

Comment: Wow, that's incredible! Tested and done the job - thank you very much!

Comment: I actually have the data in one column already, but I separated each word to make it easier to search through (so I thought)... 

Assuming the text in K:Z in one column (e.g. column H), is it just a matter of removing the query, transpose, query section?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).